# How can I use behat to check the content of a title tag?

Tags: php, html, css, behat

I'm currently testing out some changes that I've made to a CMS. This CMS auto generates  tags for each page and I would like to create a test that makes sure that the title is correct.

I can only figure out how to do this by adding a css class to the title tag and then checking to see if that element with that css class has the right text. Is there a way to just check the content of the title tag?

Answer (score 0):

Find element and use `getAttribute('title')`. After that, compare with the desired title or use an assert, and throw an error if it is not the same.

You could create a step like:
the title of the "element_selector" should be "desired title"